# RxJava RxAndroid Disposable assignation

Tags: android, rx-android

Is it ok if a disposable is reused when onNext/onError is called?

I don't quite understand why a disposable is needed, on old versions of rxJava with retrofit a disposable was not needed. I also assume when the activity or the fragment is destroyed the disposable should be disposed?

Is this the correct approach?

```
    disposable = db.databaseDao().getCategories().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { if (it.isEmpty()) addDefaultCategories() },
            { it.printStackTrace() }
        )
```

For me, this part is a little complicated. Sorry for the question that might be stupid for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that approach is perfectly fine.

Disposables make sure you don't leave any memory leaks. If the RX stream is not finished and the Activity/Fragment/ViewModel where the stream is invoked gets destroyed you will end up with a memory leak.

Since I almost always call the RX stream from my ViewModel I have the following the make my life easier:

```
open class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun addDisposable(disposable: Disposable) {
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mind if i ask if it is possible to use disposable in mvp , because in the presenter the logic takes place but since i cant call ondestroy where to clear the disposable , is there any to do in mvp

Comment: Great question! I posted an answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62991727/3014546 hope it helps!