# Clearning CompositeDisposable in MVP

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp

I'm implementing a retrofit api call and observing data using rxjava in MVP Architecture , the problem is that i have no clue on how to use disposable since it is not possible to call ondestroy() where we can clear our observer , any idea guys on how to do that , thank you

- This is my api call

```
class Presenter(var iView: IView,var context: Context) : IPresenter {
 override fun getGlobalData() {

       RetrofitSingleton().getGlobalStats()
           ?.subscribe(object : Observer<GlobalModel>{
           override fun onComplete() {

           }
           override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
             //here i add disposable but how to clear it 

           }
           override fun onNext(t: GlobalModel) {
               val cases = t.cases
               val death = t.deaths
               val recovered = t.recovered
               iView.getGlobalList(cases!!, death!!, recovered!!)
           }

           override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
               Log.d("TAG","Exception ${e.message}")
           }
       })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we don't have a method in the Presenter like we do have `onCleared()` in ViewModels it's highly recommended to make our presenters aware of the lifecycle. We should have methods like onViewAttached/onViewDetached that we will call from our fragment corresponding methods.

Example:

```
public abstract class IPresenter {
    public void onViewAttached();
    public void onViewDetached();
    // Other IPresenter methods
}
```

In our base fragment:

```
public class BaseFragment<T extends IPresenter> extends Fragment {
    protected T mPresenter;
    
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (mPresenter != null) {
            mPresenter.onViewAttached();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
            if (mPresenter != null) {
                mPresenter.onViewDetached();
            }
    }
}
```

In your presenter:

```
public void onViewAttached() {
    mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
}

public void onViewDetached() {
    if (mCompositeDisposable != null) {
        mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    }
}
```

You should add each disposable in `mCompositeDisposable` whenever you use RX, like:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

I don't know how your fragments/presenters are structured but I think this should be enough to give you the general idea. If you need more help please send me some more code I will try to adjust the same according to your code.

There is a good article about how to achive this so feel free to take a look:
https://medium.com/@jospedrocardoso/mvp-an-android-implementation-using-rxjava2-48fb377aa5cd

Comment: i guess i understand your code but inside the onViewAttached () and onViewDetached() ,  should i clear my compositeDisposable , i mean what logic to do in there thank you

Comment: Hey @takieddine sorry my bad, I've edited the answer please see if this makes it more clear on how to use it!

Comment: Thank you so much buddy for the good answer , just one thing if you don't mind , in my project im using viewpager with an activity that holds three fragments , after making my first fragment with parameter T : IPresenter now the viewpager is not recongnizing the fragment , this is a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/x2vvbnb , any solution

Comment: Well, since you declared T extends IPresenter, now when creating the fragment instance you should tell what T is. If you are using Presenter as your example above, you should declare your fragment like:
TotalFragment<Presenter>(). 

T extends IPresenter means we are declaring a type T in our fragment that can be any class that implements the IPresenter interface.
Generics are pretty tricky it takes some time before you get comfortable using them.
Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you, all best!